# Prove: If $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$ is not row-equivalent to $I_n$ then the RREF of $A$ contains a zero-row.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Prove: If $A \in Mat_{n,n}(\mathbb F)$ is not row-equivalent to $I_n$ then the RREF of $A$ contains a zero-row.

I've been thinking how to prove this statement rigorously. Indeed, looking at the definition of  REF (*RREF is a special case*) it seems to be true.

My idea is:

Suppose $A$ has pivot in columns $\{n_1, .., n_j\}$, then these pivots must be in the first $j$ rows (I don't know how to justify this rigorously either). In these columns all other entries must be zero (RREF), and in the remaining columns $\{1,..,n\} - \{n_1, .., n_j\}$ there cannot be a non-zero entry in a row lower than $j$ ?

Comment: You can always interchange rows to get the pivot rows to be the first $j$ rows. These will be the only nonzero rows in your matrix, or you'd have more pivot rows and hence more pivot columns.

Comment: So that's the proof or ?

Comment: Well, if $j < n$, then $A$ is not row equiv. to the identity matrix and has $n-j$ rows of zeros. This should help you put together a proof.

Comment: Equivalently you could try and prove that if the RREF of A contains no zero-rows then A is row-equivalent to the identity matrix. Then this is obvious from the definition of RREF on a square matrix, but perhaps this is not the type of proof you were looking for...

Answer (score 0):

Constructive proof:

For $i=1$ to $n-1$ do the following:

1. If row $i$ is a zero row, use a series of row exchange operations to move it to row $n$. If all rows $i$ to $n$ are zero we are done.
2. perform a type two row operation ($k\times $ Row$_i$) on row $i$ to make its first entry 1.
3. Use a series of type three row operations ($k\times $Row$_i+$Row$_j$) on row $j=(i+1$ to $n$) so that every entry in column $i$, except entry $(i,i)$ (which is 1) is zero.
4. If at any stage a zero row results, use a (series of) row exchange operations to move it to the bottom of the matrix, else...
   next step

After this you will either have:

1. a matrix in which the first $n-1$ columns are columns of $I_n$ and then row $n$ will have a single nonzero entry in the last column- so that you can just multiply this row by a constant $k$ and then you have $I_n$,
2. OR you will have a matrix (in REF) with at least one zero-row. In this case you must just work back from the first non-zero row using a series of type III row operations to get to RREF, but this will not affect the zero row(s) which are already there.

Comment: Why are we done if a zero row results ? We must continue until matrix is in RREF before concluding anything ? Thanks for your post.

Comment: You're done because the point is to prove a zero row exists. If you've reached this at any stage, the proof can terminate immediately.

Comment: hi sorry - you wanted a rigorous proof -...my intention was simply that once you have a zero-row you can just use a (series of) row exchange operations to move it to the bottom of the matrix and then you can continue with RREF on all the nonzero rows...I have edited my answer...